# Subtracting two text variables

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have three variables:

The main string:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

The first sub string:

```
over the lazy dog.
```

And second sub string:

```
the lazy dog.
```

I am trying to isolate the word "over" by subtracting the first string form th esecond string.

Edit:

Solved by taking the length of the long string and subtracting it form the length of the second string. Then using that value as a substring on the first string.

Comment: → http://regular-expressions.info…!?

Comment: How exactly do you know the `21` and `-12` lengths, yet don't know the length of the string you're looking for?

Comment: What about splitting the string in components (using pace as a delimiter) and reconstructing the two parts? This can work only if you know upfront the basic structure of the string (i.e. number of fields, their order and meaning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substring(), because you know the start segment length, and the end segment length.

```
var metar = document.getElementById("metartext").innerHTML;
var result = metar.substring(21, metar.length - 11);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match everything after the first whitespace with `/\s+(.*)/`:

```js
var s = "CAVOK 18/13 Q1025";
var m = s.match(/\s+(.*)/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (the first whitespaces will get matched)
- `(.*)` - zero or more characters other than CR/LF (all the rest of the line).

Answer (score 0):

This should work--

```js
var cloud1 = "CAVOK 18/13 Q1025";
var cloud2 = "18/13 Q1025";

var result = cloud1.replace(' '+cloud2,'');

console.log(result)
```

The code replaces the part of cloud1 that matches cloud2 with nothing. Therefore you are left with the first bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use use the `replace` method on the full string and replace the outputs with "" to get the result

```
var cloud = cloud1.replace(cloud2, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it from the original string with regex.

```js
var metar = 'YSSY 161000Z 02007KT CAVOK 18/13 Q1025';
var result = metar.match(/(?:.{20}\s)(\S*)(?:\s.{11})/)[1];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using lengths with [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and match the **word** that is before the date in format "18/13":

```js
var metar = document.getElementById("metartext").innerHTML,
    result = /(\w+) [0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/.exec(metar);

result && console.log(result[1]); // CAVOK
```

```html
<p id="metartext">YSSY 161000Z 02007KT CAVOK 18/13 Q1025</p>
```